# How to display a SearchBox in CommandBar

Tags: uwp-xaml, autosuggest, search-box, commandbar

I would like to add a `AutoSuggestBox` in the `CommandBar`. However the following code does not make the `AutoSuggestBox` stretch. I tried setting the `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` and `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`, but it has no impact. What am I missing?

```
    <CommandBar Grid.Row="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <AutoSuggestBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="8 8 8 4" PlaceholderText="Search podcasts" QueryIcon="Find">
                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="QuerySubmitted">
                        <Core:InvokeCommandAction                         
                    Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"
                    InputConverter="{StaticResource QueryArgsConverter}" />
                    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </AutoSuggestBox>
        </CommandBar.Content>
    </CommandBar>
```

[image: error image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I tried setting the HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" and HorizontalAlignment="Stretch", but it has no impact.

Setting [`Horizontal​Alignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.horizontalalignment) to `stretch` means an element stretched to fill the entire layout slot of the parent element. In your code snippet, the `AutoSuggestBox` is inside the content of the `CommandBar`, if we checked the [default template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299118.aspx) of `CommandBar`, the content of the `CommandBar` using a [`Content​Control`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol). So actually the parent element is a `ContentControl` not the `CommandBar` directly. It seems like the size of `ContentControl` here is depend on its child size, so that `AutoSuggestBox` has no space to fill.

Actually the content area is designed aligned to the left side of the bar. Details see Anatomy of [app bars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/app-bars). So I don't recommend  you to stretch it. You may consider using other controls as the container of the `AutoSuggestBox`. If you do want to have stretch effect you may calculate the width of `AutoSuggestBox` manually. For example:

```
<CommandBar x:Name="cmdbar">
    <CommandBar.Content>
        <AutoSuggestBox
            x:Name="autobox"
            Width="{Binding ElementName=cmdbar, Path=ActualWidth}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            PlaceholderText="Search podcasts"
            QueryIcon="Find" />
    </CommandBar.Content>
</CommandBar>
```